# How to ping website using PHP?

Tags: ping

So anyways, I'm working on a small PHP website/script, and as one of the features I'd like to be able to run a Ping Test on the current domain the PHP script is running on. I don't know much about Ping test (well, I know what they do, I just don't know how to run them in PHP) Please let me know how to do it and get same result as : http://www.ipfingerprints.com/ping.php

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)

Comment: You can't ping a website. You can ping a server.

Comment: Pay me and I will knock up summat? But where are you having a problem? Writing code?

Comment: @EdHeal i hhave Problem writing a code !

Comment: @YassinSterno - Well either employ somebody how can or read a book on PHP

Comment: @EdHeal So please help me i need lot of thing in my script how can i contact you ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method to running a ping test in PHP, you must use `exec` to run the command.

```
exec('ping -n 4 $ip', $output, $retval);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send ICMP packets in php you can take a look at this [Native-PHP ICMP ping implementation](http://code.blitzaffe.com/pages/phpclasses/files/php_icmp_ping_55-16), but I didn't test it.